# mysql insert error with uft-8 unicode

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

I want to insert some simple data
the query is:
INSERT INTO `categories_lang`(category_id,language_id,name,description,alias) VALUES (7,'nl','éésgdsfgsdfgdfsgë','','')
the query is correct
it works when I insert normal chars (no french things like ë and é).
But when I do, the query inserts an empty description field in the table.

When I run the query in heidsql , it does work.

What can be wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html):

> The default character set for th MySQL
>   client programs mysql, mysqladmin,
>   mysqlcheck, mysqlimport, and mysqlshow
>   is determined as follows:
>
> - In the absence of other information, the programs use the
>     compiled-in default character set,
>     usually *latin1*.
> - The programs support a `--default-character-set option`,
>     which enables users to specify the
>     character set explicitly to override
>     whatever default the client otherwise
>     determines.
>
> When a client connects to the server,
>   it sends the name of the character set
>   that it wants to use. The server uses
>   the name to set the
>   `character_set_client`,
>   `character_set_results`, and
>   `character_set_connection` system
>   variables. In effect, the server
>   performs a `SET NAMES` operation using
>   the character set name.
>
> With the mysql client, if you want to
>   use a character set different from the
>   default, you could explicitly execute
>   `SET NAMES` every time you start up.
>   However, to accomplish the same result
>   more easily, you can add the
>   `--default-character-set` option
>   setting to your mysql command line or
>   in your option file. For example, the
>   following option file setting changes
>   the three connection-related character
>   set variables set to koi8r each time
>   you invoke mysql:
>
> ```
> [mysql]
> default-character-set=koi8r
> ```
>
> If you are using the mysql client with
>   auto-reconnect enabled (which is not
>   recommended), it is preferable to use
>   the charset command rather than `SET
>   NAMES`. For example:
>
> ```
> mysql> charset utf8
> Charset changed
> ```
>
> The charset command issues a `SET
>   NAMES` statement, and also changes the
>   default character set that mysql uses
>   when it reconnects after the
>   connection has dropped.

Answer (score 2):

Before executing your query, send this one to server:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Note, that is is exactly 'utf8', not 'utf-8'.

If you want to avoid related problems in the future, I advice you to do `SET NAMES utf8` every time right after connecting to mysql - it will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: What exactly does this do? What does the "names" mean?